# Doubt about array of function pointers declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers

I've managed to make a "Pointer-to-member function array" with this code, and it works fine...

```
typedef string (MyReportHelper::*reportFunctions)();
MyReportHelper helper;

void internalPointersTest(){
    reportFunctions reportFunArray[] = {
        &MyReportHelper::getVersion,
        &MyReportHelper::getModel,
        &MyReportHelper::getUsername,
    };
    int arrSize = sizeof(reportFunArray)/sizeof(reportFunArray[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        string result = (helper.*reportFunArray[i])();
        printf("%s", result);
    }
}
```

But if I put the array declaration outside my function, like the following code, I get a **buffer overrun** or **access violation** in Visual Studio, though the **code compiles**.

```
typedef string (MyReportHelper::*reportFunctions)();
MyReportHelper helper;

reportFunctions reportFunArray[] = 
{
    &MyReportHelper::getVersion,
    &MyReportHelper::getModel,
    &MyReportHelper::getUsername,
};

void internalPointersTest(){
    int arrSize = sizeof(reportFunArray)/sizeof(reportFunArray[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        //next line will fail
        string result = (helper.*reportFunArray[i])();
        printf("%s", result);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to explain why I need to keep it inside the function scope?

Comment: Is that code inside some class? Or top-level? Where does the variable `helper` come from? Also, can we see the definitions of `getVersion`, `getModel` and `getUsername`?

Comment: Yes, it's in a class, but I've been able to reproduce it with top-level functions changing what was seen in here: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/4639/). 
I've edited to add the `helper` declaration

Comment: What happens if you replace `i < arrSize` with `i < 3`?

Comment: Do you have the array in a different translation unit? If so, can we see the declaration and the definition?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't index into the array with `i`.

Secondly, use `std::begin` and `std::end`, they already took care of this shit for you.

Finally, PTMFs are basically worthless. Use `std::function`.

Edit:

What probably happened is that you cocked up the size calculation and VS only happens to notice when it's static. It's probably equally broken in both versions. That's UB for you.

Edit again: You passed an object of type `string` to `printf`? If that's *not* a typedef for `const char*`, then hello UB. And if it *is*... then owch, that's really bad.

Comment: Oops, edited for right index. I'll have a look on std::function, but I still don't get it why it fails outside my function...

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = (helper.*reportFunArray[i])();
printf("%s", result);
```

I assume `string` is actually `std::string`? Are you `using namespace std;` somewhere?

In that case, `printf("%s", result);` will most likely crash, because it will interpret god-knows-what as the first character of a C-style string. Does the following work?

```
string result = (helper.*reportFunArray[i])();
std::cout << result;
```

Comment: i'm using std::string, but that printf is just an example. The problem itself is not on printf, but on `(helper.*reportFunArray[i])()`